Vuejs - how to add code to build without template
I have some components that I build with Vite which works fine
import './bootstrap'

import { createApp } from 'vue'

const app = createApp({});

app.mount('#app')

I also have this piece of code that I need to add in but I've got no idea how to do it. It doesn't have a template and the html is already declared elsewhere. I just want Vue to be able to detect click events in the DOM.
I've seen ways where you use a CDN to grab Vue but seeing as I already build with it, it seems pointless. I just need a way I can add this code to the build.
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
            windowHeight: window.innerHeight,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        // Add a global event listener
        // for window resize
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowSizeChange);

        document.getElementsByClassName('.arrow-collapse')
                .addEventListener('click', this.handleArrowCollapseClick(e));

        document.getElementsByClassName('.js-menu-toggle')
                .addEventListener('click', this.handleJsMenuToggleClick(e));

        window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUpEvent(e));
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        // Remove the event listener when
        // the component is destroyed
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowSizeChange);
        window.removeEventListener('click', this.handleArrowCollapseClick);
        window.removeEventListener('click', this.handleJsMenuToggleClick);
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUpEvent);
    },
    methods: {
        handleWindowSizeChange() {
            // Update data properties with 
            // new window dimensions
            this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
            this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

            if(transferableAbortSignal.windowWidth > 768) {
                if(document.body.classList.contains('offcanvas-menu')) {
                    document.body.classList.remove('offcanvas-menu')
                }  
            }
        },
        handleArrowCollapseClick(e) {
            if(e.closest('li')
                .querySelector('.collapse')
                .classList.contains('show')) {
                    document.querySelector('.arrow-collapse').classList.remove('active')
                } else {
                    document.querySelector('.arrow-collapse').classList.add('active')
                }
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        handleJsMenuToggleClick(e) {
            if(document.body.classList.contains('offcanvas-menu')) {
                document.body.classList.remove('offcanvas-menu');
                e.target.classList.remove('active')
            } else {
                document.body.classList.add('offcanvas-menu');
                e.target.classList.add('active')
            }
            e.preventDefault();  
        },
        handleMouseUpEvent() {
            var container = document.querySelector('.site-mobile-menu');
            if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                if(document.body.classList.contains('offcanvas-menu')) {
                    document.body.classList.remove('offcanvas-menu');
                }
            }
        }
    },
});

I did think about trying to create a plugin but not sure if I've done it right.
const MyPlugin = {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.mixin({
      Vue.handleWindowSizeChange = function() {
        // Update data properties with 
        // new window dimensions
        this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

        if(transferableAbortSignal.windowWidth > 768) {
          if(document.body.classList.contains('offcanvas-menu')) {
            document.body.classList.remove('offcanvas-menu')
          }  
        }
      },
      Vue.handleArrowCollapseClick = function(e) {
        if(e.closest('li')
          .querySelector('.collapse')
          .classList.contains('show')) {
            document.querySelector('.arrow-collapse').classList.remove('active')
          } else {
            document.querySelector('.arrow-collapse').classList.add('active')
          }
        e.preventDefault();
      },
      Vue.handleArrowCollapseClick = function(e) {
        if(e.closest('li')
            .querySelector('.collapse')
            .classList.contains('show')) {
                document.querySelector('.arrow-collapse').classList.remove('active')
            } else {
                document.querySelector('.arrow-collapse').classList.add('active')
            }
        e.preventDefault();
      },
      Vue.handleJsMenuToggleClick = function(e) {
        if(document.body.classList.contains('offcanvas-menu')) {
            document.body.classList.remove('offcanvas-menu');
            e.target.classList.remove('active')
        } else {
            document.body.classList.add('offcanvas-menu');
            e.target.classList.add('active')
        }
        e.preventDefault();  
      },
      Vue.handleMouseUpEvent = function() {
        var container = document.querySelector('.site-mobile-menu');
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
          if(document.body.classList.contains('offcanvas-menu')) {
            document.body.classList.remove('offcanvas-menu');
          }
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        // Add a global event listener
        // for window resize
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowSizeChange);

        document.getElementsByClassName('.arrow-collapse')
                .addEventListener('click', this.handleArrowCollapseClick(e));

        document.getElementsByClassName('.js-menu-toggle')
                .addEventListener('click', this.handleJsMenuToggleClick(e));

        window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUpEvent(e));
      },
    });
  }
};

export default MyPlugin;


The reason why there can be such code with CDN is because it avoids creating components explicitly (data(), etc belong to anonymous root component). There's no problem with defining comps when you build an app. "I have some components" - this isn't shown. Generally you just add code that is global to the app to root component (App.vue), but you could add it to createApp({}) the same way it was done with new Vue({})
